# TypeError: object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I`ve obtain this error

```
  File "/class.py", line 246, in __init__
if d and self.rf == 2 and d["descriptionType"] in ["900000000000003001"] and d["conceptId"] in konZer.zerrenda:
TypeError: 'Desk' object is not subscriptable
```

I created this object

```
class Desk:
     descriptionId = ""
     descriptionStatus = ""
     conceptId = ""
     term = ""
```

And I called it in another class

```
class DescriptionList():

     def deskJ(self,line):
         er = line.strip().split('\t')
         desc = Desk()
         if er[1] == "0":
            desc.descriptionId = er[0]
            desc.descriptionStatus = er[1]
            desc.conceptId = er[2]
            desc.term = er[3]
         return description
```

Then I called the function "deskJ" at **init** and I get the error at this part (I've deleted some parts of the function):

```
def __init__(self,fitx,konZer,lanZer={}):
        with codecs.open(fitx,encoding='utf-8') as fitx:
            lines = fitx.read().split('\n')[1:-1]
            for line in lines:
                d = self.deskJ(line)
                if d and self.rf == 2 and d["descriptionType"] in ["900000000000003001"] and d["conceptId"] in konZer.zerrenda:
                    c = konZer.zerrenda[d["conceptId"]]
                    c["fullySpecifiedName"] = d["term"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `d["descriptionType"]` is trying to access `d` with the key `"descriptionType"`.  That doesn't work, though, because `d` is a `Desk` object that doesn't have keys.  Instead, get the attributes:

```
if d and self.rf == 2 and d.descriptionType in ["900000000000003001"] and d.conceptId in konZer.zerrenda:
```

Comment: what if you had a different requirement and you wanted to reference attributes using a variable name?  How would you rewrite something like d[attr_var] assuming attr_var contained some string which corresponded to a column name.

Comment: @Sledge: There's a builtin function for that: `getattr(d, attr_var)`